# Translate Sorted Set to a Range Statement in Java

Tags: java

I have a Sorted Set with elements as [1,2,3,4,5,10,12,45,46,47,50]

I need to convert this set as a Range Statement where continuous elements are represented with min .. max.
To be precise here is the expected output.

1..5/10/12/45..47/50

Since 1 to 5 are continuous they are denoted by 1..5 and so as 45..47

10,12 etc.. are discontinuous and hence they are separated by Union.

Can anyone help me any inbuilt method or efficient Algorithm to achieve this?
Currently I am using iterators over set but stuck in middle.

```
String SetToRange(Set<Integer> S, long maxint)
    {
        Integer min,max;
        StringBuilder Range=new StringBuilder("");
        Iterator I=S.iterator();
        switch(S.size())
        {
            case 0: Range.append("0.."+maxint);
                    System.out.println("RangeStatement for Set Size 0 is"+Range);
                    return Range.toString();
            case 1: min=max=(Integer)I.next();
                    Range.append(min);
                    System.out.println("RangeStatement="+Range);    
                    return Range.toString();
            case 2: min=(Integer)I.next();
                    max=(Integer)I.next();
                    if(max==min+1)
                    {
                        Range.append(min.toString()+".."+max.toString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Range.append(min+"\\/"+max);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Range Statement:-"+Range);
                    return Range.toString();
        }
         System.out.println("The Set has more than Two Elements="+S.size());
         min=(Integer)I.next();
         max=(Integer)I.next();
         //Working out logic for this Part using Two Iterators
         return Range.toString();

    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: You mean stuck due to logic or performance ?

Comment: Logic because, I am using Two iterators.. I want to find a way to use only one iterator or no Iterators to achieve this. I need some direction to start for a good approach

Comment: I can think of an algorithm to do this in O(n) time and space. What have you tried so far? Do you have any code?

Comment: Function Code Added in the Post...

Comment: What is the point of the switch? Why not have a class to represent the range? This whole thing smells of procedural code in an OO language.

Comment: Decomposing a problem into smaller pieces is what OO is all about. Step 1 should be to get the ranges. Step 2 is convert to a string. Otherwise, you have two concerns interfering in the same code, increasing the likelihood of bugs and decreasing the understandability.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in `O(n)` time. This example shows it with an oriented-object approach.

First create a `Range` class.

```
class Range {
    int from;
    int to;

    public Range setFrom(int from) {
        this.from = from;
        return this;
    }

    public Range setTo(int to) {
        this.to = to;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Range [from=" + from + ", to=" + to + "]";
    }   
}
```

Now just iterate through the array and compare the adjacent elements.

If their difference is superior than 1, they are not contiguous so you set the upperbound of the previous range, you add it to the list and you create a new one setting its lower bound.

```
public class Test { 

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Set<Integer> setOfIntegers = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,10,12,45,46,47,49));
        System.out.println(getRanges(setOfIntegers));
    }

    public static List<Range> getRanges(Set<Integer> s){
        List<Range> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer[] setOfIntegers = s.toArray(new Integer[s.size()]);

        Range r = new Range().setFrom(setOfIntegers[0]);
        for(int i = 1; i < setOfIntegers.length; i++){
             if(setOfIntegers[i] - setOfIntegers[i-1] != 1){
                 list.add(r.setTo(setOfIntegers[i-1]));
                 r = new Range().setFrom(setOfIntegers[i]);
             }
        }
        list.add(r.setTo(setOfIntegers[setOfIntegers.length-1]));

        return list;
    }
}
```

Some outputs:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,10,12,45,46,47,49] => [Range [from=1, to=5], Range [from=10, to=10], Range [from=12, to=12], Range [from=45, to=47], Range [from=49, to=49]]

[4,7,8,9,15,20,21] => [Range [from=4, to=4], Range [from=7, to=9], Range [from=15, to=15], Range [from=20, to=21]]

[-17,-6,-4,-3,-2,0,1,4] => [Range [from=-17, to=-17], Range [from=-6, to=-6], Range [from=-4, to=-2], Range [from=0, to=1], Range [from=4, to=4]]
```

Note that I didn't check if the set has no elements, etc. But you have the general idea and it should not be that hard to modify it as your needs.

Answer (score 0):

So, your basic function is:

```
f(List<int>) => List<List<int>>
```

Such that the output's inner list is guaranteed to have only consecutive numbers, and no two such lists have consecutive numbers. So your algorithm looks something like:

```
sort(List<int> input)
  List<List<int>> output = new List<List<Int>>();
  while (input.hasElements())
    output.append( getNextConsecutive(input))//NOTE: getNextConsecutive modifies input!
  return output

getNextConsecutive(List<int> input)
  List<int> output = new List<int>();
  while (input.next() == ouput.last() + 1) {
    output.append(input.pop);//note: removes from input
  }
  return output
```

Note that this algorithm elides output, because it is a separate concern and should be naturally handled by another function:

```
printLists(List<List<int>> input)
  for each List in input, sublist
    if sublist.length > 1
      print sublist.first
      print ".."
      print sublist.last
    if sublist.length == 1
      print sublist.first
  print "/"
```

Comment: This is pseudocode, not actual code, as evidenced by lack of, say, Java syntax. Use `Integer` if you need your primitive boxed.

Comment: It was more to warn new programmers than to imply you didn't know better. Using primitives is a common mistake, and your code is close enough to real Java syntax to be deceiving.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Solution for your question.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class SetRange {

    public static String getRangeString(Set<Integer> rangeSet) {

        StringBuffer strBuilder = new StringBuffer();
        Integer lastValue = null;
        boolean contineous = false;
        for (Integer value : rangeSet) {
            if (lastValue != null && lastValue + 1 == value.intValue()) {
                contineous = true;
            } else {
                if (contineous) {
                    strBuilder.deleteCharAt(strBuilder.length() - 1);
                    strBuilder.append(".." + lastValue + "/" + value + "/");
                } else {
                    strBuilder.append(value + "/");
                }
                contineous = false;

            }
            lastValue = value;
        }
        String answer = strBuilder.toString();
        if (answer.length() > 0) {
            answer = answer.substring(0, answer.length() - 1);
        }
        return answer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> rangeSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        rangeSet.add(1);
        rangeSet.add(2);
        rangeSet.add(3);
        rangeSet.add(4);
        rangeSet.add(5);
        rangeSet.add(10);
        rangeSet.add(12);
        rangeSet.add(45);
        rangeSet.add(46);
        rangeSet.add(47);
        rangeSet.add(50);

        String answer = getRangeString(rangeSet);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```