# Grouping an array of integers that skip numbers in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Say I have the following `int array`:

```
[1,2,3,6,7, 8, 9,20, 22]
```

I'd like to be able to display to the user the following based off the above `array`:

```
Numbers 1 through 3, 6 through 9, 20, 22
```

How could I go about doing this?  Essentially checking if the number previous equals the current number - 1?  Guess I just answered my own question, but any shortcuts/pointers would be welcome.

Note: only dealing with integers, nothing negative (wouldn't be an integer would it).

Comment: Integer numbers by definition include negative numbers. What doesn't include negative numbers are *natural* numbers. That said, really doesn't matter if numbers are negative or not in your problem.

Comment: Is the input already sorted?

Comment: You can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070332/translate-sorted-set-to-a-range-statement-in-java/23070645

Comment: Have you written any code/tried anything yet? It's easier to optimize actual code than theoretical code.

Comment: Wow 4 answers all with negative votes lol

Comment: @ssedano I apologize I  posted this and was wiped last night, so I went to bed.  Yes the input is sorted already.  Wish I'd done some coding as well but been extremely busy until now.

Comment: just upvoted all the -1 answers to restore balance to the universe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A live example using Ideone can be found [here](https://ideone.com/QSZZTw). Runs in `O(n)` time.

---

```
Integer[] A = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 22};
int start = 0, end;

System.out.print("Numbers ");                 
while((end = start) < A.length){
    // Increment the 'end' pointer while consecutive numbers exist.
    while(end + 1 < A.length && A[end + 1] == A[end] + 1) end++;

    // If end == start: 'A[start]'
    // Else           : 'A[start] through A[end]'
    System.out.print(A[start] + 
                     (end == start ? "":(" through " + A[end])) +  
                     (end < A.length - 1 ? ", ":""));

    // Increment start pointer to next element in A
    start = end + 1;
}
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but I'm guessing that it's because just the downvoter thought that giving an answer for OP to copy/paste isn't really being helpful to him/her.

Comment: @user3580294 I would agree, I was more looking for theory than actual code.  But I'll take it non-the less. I understand the principle behind it anyways.

Comment: @Eric if it helped, could you select it as the correct answer?

Comment: @bcorso Done,though I had to fix the code up a bit as it always ended with a comma.

Just created a `StringBuilder` and removed the last comma outside of the `while` loop, other than that works perfectly.

Comment: @Eric, you could also just add a conditional for the comma. I've added that to the code.

Comment: @bcorso either way does work though :P  And honestly I find conditionals a bit harder to read when debugging, but that's just me.

Comment: @bcorso almost perfect, but would you mind adding comments/explanations as to how the snippet works?

Comment: @JosephusVillarey added some comments, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best looking code, but works:

```
public static void display(int[] input) {
    String out = "Numbers ";
    int first = input[0];
    int last = -1;
    int older = first;
    for (int i : input) {
        if (i == older + 1) {
            last = i;
            older++;
        } else if (i > older + 1) {
            out += last > first ? first + " through " + last + ", " : first + ", ";
            first = i;
            older = i;
        }
        if (i == input[input.length - 1]) {
            out += last > first ? first + " through " + last : first;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(out);
}
```

Example:

```
int[] in1 = { 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 22 };
int[] in2 = { 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 21, 22 };
display(in1);
display(in2);
```

Outputs:

```
Numbers 1 through 3, 6 through 9, 20, 22
Numbers 1 through 3, 6 through 9, 20 through 22
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
int[] numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 20, 22];
int rangeStart = -999;
int rangeEnd = -999;
for (int n : numberArray) {
    if (n > rangeEnd + 1) {
        if (rangeEnd = -999) {
            System.out.print("Numbers ");
        else if (rangeEnd > rangeStart) {
            System.out.printf("%d through %d, ", rangeStart, rangeEnd);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%d, ", rangeEnd);
        }
        rangeStart = rangeEnd = n;
    } else {
        rangeEnd = n;
    }
}
if (rangeEnd > rangeStart) {
    System.out.printf("%d through %d, ", rangeStart, rangeEnd);
} else {
    System.out.printf("%d,", rangeEnd);
}
```

Might need some fine-tuning regarding the use of commas and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my terrible formatting, just some psuedocode you can think about.

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    start = int[i]
    compare int[i] to int[i+1] {
        if true, store as end, compare to next in array
        else, break out
    }

    if start != end, print start through end
    else, print start
}
```

**edit: and increment i to be the last + 1